# Extract more Strings with regex in Android

Tags: java, android, regex

Input is something like this:

```
String text = "{\"definitions\":[{\"id\":\"com.sample.evaluationa\",\"name\":\"Evaluationa\",\"vers}{\"id\":\"com.sample.evaluationb\",\"name\":\"Evaluationb\",\"vers}";
```

And some quotes to make it more transparent

```
String definitions = "{\"definitions\":[";
String id = "{\"id\":\"";
String name = "\",\"name\":\"";
String rest = "\",\"vers}";
```

My regular expression then looks like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile((Pattern.quote(definitions)) +"("+ (Pattern.quote(id)) +"(.+)" +(Pattern.quote(name))+"(.+)"+(Pattern.quote(rest))+")*");
```

I am looking for id's (com.sample.evaluation)

```
Matcher regexMatcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        title = regexMatcher.group(2);
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println("The pattern is " + pattern.pattern());
    }
```

My output looks like this:

```
com.sample.evaluationa","name":"Evaluationa","vers}{"id":"com.sample.evaluationb
The pattern is \Q{"definitions":[\E(\Q{"id":"\E(.+)\Q","name":"\E(.+)\Q","vers}\E)*
```

But I want:

```
com.sample.evaluationacom.sample.evluationb
```

And what is also interesting but not in the good way, after changing targeted group in cycle

```
title = regexMatcher.group(2);
```

I get just (and of course the pattern line)

```
Evaluationb
```

Comment: I'd really recommend using a JSON parser.

Comment: Seriously, use something like Jackson.  The path you are going down is like building a house with spoons.

Comment: In that you'd be forked.

Comment: True, making Json into String and then parsing this string with regex wasn't good idea. It's just I am newbie in this things so I am making simple things too much complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle that string in your java, just download [Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library 
and paste the  `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` file to your **libs** folder

And use it like this

```
String formatedjsonstring=StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(yourjsonstring);
```

Don't make the things complicated..Use this library which will automatically unescape the characters

After you java escape the characters create Json Object like this

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(formatedjsonstring);
JSONArray jsonArray=obj.getJSONArray("definitions");
```

Than use for loop to parse those json objects

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
JSONObject obj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
String id=obj.getString("id");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.+` means **1** to **infinite** characters and the regex engine is by default **greedy** so it will match as many characters as possible.

It would be better to define classes of characters that you can expect there:
`[a-z\.]+` for `id`  and `[A-Z][a-z]+` for `name`
those will work by themselves because when hitting the `\` the regex engine will stop as `\` is not part of the last class

If you by any reason want to use `.+` but stop as early as possible add a `?` after so it will switch to **lazy** behaviour. (eg. `.+?`)